# How do I STOP an Azure BizTalk Service without deleting it?

Tags: azure, service, biztalk, preview

Even at current preview pricing, I'd still like to be able to turn off the service(s) to save some $$.  But I'd rather not delete them if I don't have to.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question almost a year later.  I've found two options.
Option 1: Backup/Restore WABS service using the Azure web UI.
Option 2: Use 'suspend'/'resume' functionality using the RESTful API.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn232419.aspx)

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

That is unfortunately not possible with the current version and I fully agree with you that this should be possible.  Because with the current model, we cannot benefit from the cloud flexibility that Azure is providing with almost all other services.

I have given this feedback to the team already, but we'll see what will come from it ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it should be possible:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/biztalk-service-state-chart/

So, it's a bug ;) I hope this means they will fix it sooner.